# how to reduce flutter cloud firestone reads per day?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, back4app, cost-management

I want to create a revision/examination app for 20k+ students. I am going to take a test every day for all students (users app) of my app. and then store their records(scores) as total marks on the cloud Firestore.
so my problem is I want to display students' rank order by their scores(while sorting their total marks).
so if a student goes to the rank page to see the top students, the app will call 20k documents ordered by their total marks descending,

```
     body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('Users')
              .doc('Students')
              .collection('Regions')
              .doc('regionName')
              .collection('Districts')
              .doc('DIstrictName')
              .collection('Student_Phone')
              .orderBy('Total_Marks', descending: true)
               //time registered students
              .orderBy('Created', descending: false)  the right one
             
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {

           return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    
                      return showUsers(
                        index: index,
                        snapshot: stuSnapShot.data.docs[index],
                      );
                    });
       .......}
```

as well as I have to show '***my score page***' for the student to show him his rank this will also want to retrieve the 20k documents to iterate through using this.

```
    class showUsers extends StatefulWidget {
       var snapshot;
      final int index;
      showUsers({@required this.snapshot, @required this.index});
       @override
      _showUsersState createState() => _showUsersState();
     }

   class _showUsersState extends State<showUsers> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var numNum = widget.snapshot.data()['PhoneNumber'].toString();
      if (numNum == '+8977106429') {
 
          return Container(
             child: Text(
              'you are :${widget.index}  phone =$numNum',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
             );
            } 
           }
          }
```

. and this will cost a lot of money to the firebase cloud Firestore pricing when 20k students read 20k documents per day 20,0000 X 20,000= 400,0000,0000 ==400m reads per day, which will cost= $720 per day which equals 30 X $720=$21,600.
so is there another way to read these documents without that cost?

Comment: Why not use cloud function to save the rank on your firestore.

Comment: but how  please can you  give more information, or show sample code